# Selenium with TestNG and Gradle: Setting browser crash tests as SKIPPED instead of FAILED

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, testng, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently dealing with the usual flakiness of the latest version of Chrome and ChromeDriver with Selenium. I'm running my tests using Grid 2 and a couple of Windows 7 machines. I'll get the occasional inevitable dead browser tab being reported by ChromeDriver. Since these tests didn't really fail as far as the web app functionality, I'd like to mark them as skipped to keep reporting a bit more useful for my current purpose. I've tried getting them to re-run, but TestNG's support for this is experimental and currently broken.

Is there a way I can set these tests to a SKIPPED status before they're logged in my Gradle report? (I'm using Gradle for reporting instead of ReportNG since ReportNG doesn't work properly with parallel testing).

I'm thinking I need to add another listener and somehow pick up the reported stack trace, check for a particular string, and then set the set to SKIPPED. Is this the correct approach?

Any tips on how to accomplish this would be great. I'm not able to find a way to capture the stack trace with my listener yet, and most importantly, set the test to a SKIPPED state (once the trace is parsed). I am using Java to drive these tests.

Any ideas / help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,
Darwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to implement the interface [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html), in onTestFailure() check the stack trace and call [setCurrentTestResult()](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/Reporter.html#setCurrentTestResult%28org.testng.ITestResult%29) method to set the Skipped status.

Don't forget to make the implemented class a listener as described in '5.17 - TestNG Listeners' of TestNG documentation.

Comment: Great, that's pretty much right along the lines of what I've got happening right now, although I'm having difficulty figuring out how to actually grab the stack trace. Is there a way to capture it so it can be parsed easily?

Comment: @darwin-allen Try something like:


String stackTraceString = Throwables.getStackTraceAsString(getCurrentTestResult().getThrowable());

Comment: Great, that gives me much more to work with than the implementation I was trying out. I think I can take it from here. Much appreciated :).